# Java validate HTML string inside Java code

Tags: java, html, swing

I am trying to validate a string places in my HTML as a tag inside of my Java program so that if someone changes the HTML tag string my Java program checks the string if it is what I wrote.

Here is my java...

```
public void init()
{
    String name = getParameter("author");
    String course = getParameter("class");


    if (name == "goes here")
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Good, it will setVisible(true)", "Library System", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    if (name != "goes here")
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "NOT good and will setVisible(false)", "Library System", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    Container contain = getContentPane();
    contain.add(new LibraryPanel(name, course));
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is my HTML...

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code=3.LibraryFrame.class width=650 height=700>
    <param name=author value="goes here">
    <param name=class value="className">
</applet>

</body>
</html>
```

So when my string in my HTML tag is correct however it always says it doesnt match. I even have placed the name and course variable in my showMessageDialog and it matches.

Any ideas on why it isn't correctly validating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (name == "David Duke")
```

Never use `==` or `!=` in Java to compare strings. Use `equals()` instead:

```
if (name.equals("David Duke"))
```

Note that `==` checks if the two arguments on the left and the right of it refer to the exact same object - it does **not** check if the contents of two objects are the same.

Comment: Wonderful, I just tried .equalsignorecase() and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Always compare Strings with `equals()` and never with `==`.

It sould be

```
if ("David Duke".equals(name))
```

because `==` compares references for reference data types.

Also you can get rid of that second `if` statement and use `else` for that.

Comment: I trying to test the results, I was using many if statements to see what was going on.